# How to hide Save HTML, Edit HTML Source, Styles in HTML Editor Webpage dialog

Tags: 2007

I am using Publishing:HtmlEditor control on page and in edit mode I have to hide `Save HTML`, `Edit HTML Source`, `Styles` from popup HTMLEditor window[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `Properties` associated with the control

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="htmlfieldid" FieldName="FieldName" 
    AllowHtmlSourceEditing="false"
    runat="server"/>
```

For more properties check - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms561507(v=office.12).aspx